# Incredibly slow Java application launching on Tomcat Server in Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite)?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

please, take a look at this snapshot:

[image]

And it happens over and over when I run a new Java web application on a Tomcat Server (right click on the project -> Run -> Run on Server). Eclipse/STS (I am using STS 3.6.4 with Eclipse Luna 4.4, as you can see from the screenshot) hangs almost for an infinite time, and consumes all the CPU. 
I have the following settings inside STS.ini:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Does anyone ever experienced a similar problem? If so, what did you do? Anyway, what can I do in order to find the root cause of the issue and resolve?

I didn't experienced this problem before (I guess it started when I upgraded from STS 3.6.3 to STS 3.6.4, but I can't say that this is the cause).

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Do you have any active breakpoints during startup? If so disable all and try again.

Comment: @MartinFrey No, I don't have any breakpoint active.